# Changing a character array inside a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, function

I am facing an issue while creating a Linux module which I have simulated [here](https://ideone.com/QrRmIm).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeBuff(unsigned char ** b)
{
    *b[0] = 0x12;
    *b[1] = 0x34;
}

int main(void) {
    unsigned char * buf = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 2);
    buf[0] = 0x55;
    buf[1] = 0xAA;
    printf("%x\t%x\n", buf[0], buf[1]);
    changeBuff(&buf);
    printf("%x\t%x\n", buf[0], buf[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Long story short, I am trying to change values of an array inside a function. While the value at the first index gets changed, the same does not happen for the second index. The output of the code above is

```
55  aa
12  aa
```

Somewhat similar problems are addressed in other stackoverflow threads (e.g. [Changing an array with a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611832/changing-an-array-with-a-function-in-c), [Pass and change array inside function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429409/pass-and-change-array-inside-function-in-c), [Changing array inside function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34844003/changing-array-inside-function-in-c)) but for some reason, even using a pointer to the character array is not working in my case (as can be seen from the output of the code in the ideone link above). What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The link is not working for me. It just says "`Forbidden`"

Comment: @NullDev try now? It was set to private by default.

Comment: Yes, it works now :)

Comment: Operator precedence. You should do `(*b)[0] = 0x12`. This makes this question not related to the actual problem, and the problem is close to being a typo. Question should probably be closed/removed.

Answer (score 3):

The `[]` operator binds tighter then the `*`-operator, so change

```
*b[0] = 0x12;
```

to

```
(*b)[0] = 0x12;
```

---

Alternatively change

```
void changeBuff(unsigned char ** b)
{
  *b[0] = 0x12;
  *b[1] = 0x34;
}
```

to

```
void changeBuff(unsigned char * b)
{
  b[0] = 0x12;
  b[1] = 0x34;
}
```

and instead of calling it like this

```
  changeBuff(&buf);
```

call it like this

```
  changeBuff(buf);
```

---

Unrelated to your issue:

- There is no need to cast from/to `void`-pointers in C.
- `sizeof (char)` equals 1 by definition.

So this line

```
unsigned char * buf = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * 2);
```

is equal to this

```
unsigned char * buf = malloc(2);
```

A more robust version would be

```
unsigned char * buf = malloc(2 * sizeof *buf);
```

which would survive changing the type of where `buf` points to.

Comment: Don't put a space between the dereference operator and the pointer

Comment: Just like you shouldn't put a space between an object and an increment/decrement operator (leading/trailing).

Comment: @alk Thanks for the tips. Casting void pointers has become a habit after working in a company that puts a lot of focus on satisfying static code analysers, some of which would complain on this.

Answer (score 1):

Because of [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `*b[0]` is equivalent to `*(b[0])`, which is not you want.

Adding a pair of parentheses around `*b` is a solution:

```
(*b)[0] = 0x12;
```